# Is there has some way to keyBy broadcast?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

i use flink version 1.14.3

i have a large data (about 4Gb) that want to broadcast to a KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction, but if i broadcast the raw data to every node, it's will take up a lot of memory and low performance, so i want to know, is there has some way to use the same keySeletor rule in process function and broadcast, that can keyBy broadcast then let the specified key goes to the specified node?

Answer (score 1):

The very definition of *broadcast* is that everything is sent to every downstream node.

If instead, you have two streams that you want to key partition into the same key space, so that you can join them on that key, you can do that. Instead of a `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction` you will use a `KeyedCoProcessFunction`. That looks something like this:

```java
DataStream<A> a = env.addSource(aSource).keyBy(a -> a.key);

DataStream<B> b = env.addSource(bSource).keyBy(b -> b.key);

a.connect(b)
    .process(new MyKeyedCoProcessFunction())
    ...
```

See [the RidesAndFares exercise from the Apache Flink training](https://github.com/apache/flink-training/tree/master/rides-and-fares) for a complete example of this pattern.